# WPF binding GridView with class properties?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am new to WPF.

A class property that has array of names (reading from appconfig)

```
class Sample
{
    private string[] names; 
    public string[] Names
    {
        get
        {
        names = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserNames"].Split(',');
            return machines;
        }
        set { names = value; }
    }
}
```

I want to populate a WPF Gridview with these names.

Here is my NamesView.xaml:

```
 <ListView>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True" >
                <GridViewColumn Header="Names" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Names}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
 </ListView>
```

Here is my code behind NamesView.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class ServerView : Windows
{
    public ServerView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Sample sample = new Sample();
        this.DataContext = sample.Names;
    }
}
```

Question:

Not able to understand what is mistake? If any site or stuff is there to study, please share?

[Solved]

Actually for grid view `DataContext` is not working, I used `Itemssource` and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement that next way:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Person> GetAll()
    {
        List<Person> names = new List<Person>;
        string[] namesArray = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserNames"].Split(',');
        foreach(var name in namesArray)
        {
            names.Add(new Person { Name = name });
        }
        return names;
    }
}
```

and

```
<GridView Name="MyGridView" AllowsColumnReorder="True" >
    <GridViewColumn Header="Names" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
</GridView>
```

and

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Person all = new Person();
    MyGridView.DataSource = all.GetAll();
}
```

**Edit:** Data Context:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx

This is how MSDN defines it:

> Data context is a concept that allows
>   elements to inherit information from
>   their parent elements about the data
>   source that is used for binding, as
>   well as other characteristics of the
>   binding, such as the path.